# The set of bounded functions are dense in Hilbert Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics

I'm reading the book "Semiparametric Theory and Missing Data" by Anastasios A. Tsiatis and I'm having trouble trying to understand the following fact:

Let $Z$ be a random variable. We define $\mathcal{H}$ as the Hilbert space of q-dimensional mean-zero real-valued functions. We also require that the covariance matrix is nonsingular. That is,

$\mathcal{H} = \{ h : supp(Z) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q} \ | \ \mathbb{E}[h(Z)] = 0^{q \times 1}, \mathbb{E}[hh^T]^{-1} \text{exists} \}$

The space $\mathcal{H}$ is equipped with the covariance inner product $\langle h_1, h_2 \rangle \triangleq \mathbb{E}[h_1^T h_2]$.

On page 69, the author mentioned that "any element of $\mathcal{H}$ can be approximated by a sequence of bounded $h$" (or equivalently, the set of bounded functions is dense in $\mathcal{H}$).

Does anyone have any idea why this is true?

Comment: minor issue: wouldnt finite variance be $\mathbb{E}[h^Th]<\infty$, not $\mathbb{E}[hh^T]<\infty$? And are the functions $h$ measurable?

Comment: Because simple functions (linear combinations of set indicators) are bounded and they are [dense in any $L^p$](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/240A-C-03-04/Lecture_Notes/Older-Versions/chap22.pdf).

Comment: @Conifold while this is true, it requires some additional thought that the simple functions with mean zero are dense in the space of mean-zero functions in $L^p$.

Comment: @supinf The part on finite variance is a typo. Fixed it. functions $h$ are measurable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $h\in\mathcal H$.
Then define the bounded function $h_k$ via
$$
h_k(s):=h(s) \chi_{\{\|h(s)\|\leq k\}}-a_k,
$$
where $\chi_{\{\|h(s)\|\leq k\}}$ is $1$ if $\|h(s)\|\leq k$ and $0$ else,
and $a_k\in\mathbb R^q$.
Choose $a_k$ such that $\mathbb E[h_k(Z)]=0$
and show that $h_k\in\mathcal H$.

Finally, show that the convergence $h_k\to h$ actually holds.
You should use the norm induced by the covariance inner product here,
i.e.\ you should show
$\langle h-h_k,\,h-h_k\rangle \to0$ for $k\to\infty$.